# Writing a function to detect if the Json has any Values "{TBD}"

Tags: powershell, loops

Task: I have to write a function in PowerShell which will scan a JSON to see if it has string "{TBD}". If it does not have any "TBD" in it, print "JSON did validate" or else print "JSON did not validate".

To do this, I thought it might be better to use a regex function to find the string "Unknown". I'm not an expert at PowerShell, so if someone could look at the code I've written and suggest the right syntax that would be really helpful.

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "zrp_ConnectionStrings": [
        {
            "ConnectionName": "application-direct",
            "Provider": "Sysrepublic.Secure.Core.DataProviders.MssqlDatabaseProvider, Sysrepublic.Secure.Core"
        }
    ],
    "zrp_ConfigurationItem": [
        {
            "Name": "CPF.Core.EmailToken.{LOGONURL}",
            "DataType": "Text",
            "Value": "https://xlots.apprissretailcloud.com/zecure/cpf/auth/logon"
        },
        {
            "Name": "sso.samlCertificate",
            "DataType": "Text",
            "Value": "{TBD}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I coded:

```
$json = Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\secure_ConfigurationItem.json
$pattern = '"Value": "(.*?)",'
$ListNm= ( ([regex]::Matches($json,$pattern) ).groups | Where-Object {$_.Name -EQ 'TBD'}).value
```

Comment: You could just do `if($json -cmatch '\{TBD}') { 'did not validate' } else { 'validate' }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You are correct but now if I need to use a regex expression like I used for detecting trailing commas, what would that look like. Here is what I used for Trailing commas: [regex]::Matches($json, '("|}|])\s*,\s*(]|}|$)')

Comment: I dont understand what your regex has to do with your question

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ignore my comment. I just added a if else condition to throw the error as required depending on whether the json has TBD.  Thank you for your help